# Ciclo for para tabla de multiplicación

Tags: java, loops

Estoy aprendiendo ciclos `for`, son las tablas de multiplicar del **0** al **10**  `1 X 1 =1`.

Pero quiero probar con otros ciclo una suma así `1 X 1+1 =2` como sería usando un tercer ciclo

```
 public static  void tabla (){
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      System.out.println("Tabla de multiplicar del " + i);
            for (int j = 0; j <=10; j++) {
                //int num:0;
            System.out.println(i  + " X " + j + " =" + i*j);
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: En el primer **for** `<- 10;` debería ser `<=10`

Comment: ¿La suma siempre será +1? ¿O también irá del 1 al 10? (¿por eso mencionas un tercer ciclo for?)

Comment: sorry error de dedo es = ya lo corregi

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que quieres es modificar la operación entonces lo que debes hacer es prestar atención en esta linea en particular:

> ```
>     System.out.println(i  + " X " + j + " =" + i*j);}
> ```

En la misma es donde se realiza la operación entre:

- `i` que representa la primer variable, que es la Tabla de Multiplicar.
- `j` que representa la segunda variable, que es el Número por el cuál se multiplicará.

Como vemos entonces, al final de la linea y luego del **=** se realiza la operación `i*j` que dará como resultado las tablas.

Para realizar lo que quieres, entonces, es prescindible que añadas en esa linea las operaciones que deseas, si lo deseado es que se sume +1:

> ```
>     System.out.println(i  + " X " + j + " +1 =" + i*j+1);}
> ```

**Por lo contrario** si tu interés es **añadir un nuevo ciclo** `for`, como los otros dos, que realice una **suma a la operación de multiplicación** con los respectivos números del `loop`,tu código quedaría algo así:

```
public static  void tabla (){
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      System.out.println("Tabla de multiplicar del " + i);

            for (int j = 0; j <=10; j++) {
                for (int m = 0; m <=10; m++) {
                //int num:0;
            System.out.println(i  + " X " + j + " + " + m + " =" + i*j+m);}}
            }}
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta que pena se me ha dificultado los ciclos anidados

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría saber de que forma puedo sumar los resultados de la multiplicación que se ejecuta en el siguiente programa:

```
package edilbia;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Edilbia {

    public static void main(String[] ARGS) {

        int numero, i, j, resultado;
        int suma = 1 ;

        numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("indica la tabla de multiplicar: "));

        for (i = numero; i <= numero; i++) {
            for (j = 4; j <= 8; j++) {
                resultado = i * j;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i + " X " + j + " = " + resultado);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La suma de los resultados de las multiplicaciones es: " + suma);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, realiza tu propia pregunta en base a [ask], realiza el [tour] para que conozcas su funcionamiento. Te sugiero eliminar esta publicación.